# limit as x approaches infinity for $y=sec^{(-1)}x$

Tags: limits

I'm a beginner and I'm using a basic graphing calculator. I understand I can input $sec^{(-1)}x$ as $cos^{(-1)}(1/x)$, but even as I'm looking at the graph, I don't get it. How do I determine the answer to be $\pi/2$? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does $\sec^{-1}(x)$ mean?  Is this the multiplicative inverse of $\sec(x)$ or $arcsec(x)$?

Comment: @Hayden Based on how the question is written, it can be deduced that $\sec^{-1}(x)=\arcsec(x)$.

Comment: Hint: $x$ is getting very large, so $1/x$ is getting very close to $0$ but positive. If my cosine is very close to $0$, roughly what number (between $0$ and $\pi$) am I?

Comment: @Sanath I assumed as much, but wanted to make sure in case there was a confusion the OP was having which might have helped provide help.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Your hint was extremely helpful and helped me determine the answer.

Comment: Good. It is useful to figure out things oneself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sec^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}(1/x)$$
Take the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sec^{-1}x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos^{-1}(1/x)\to\cos^{-1}(0)=\pi/2\mbox{ in the interval $[0,\pi]$.}$$